# How to correctly setup AccessToken validation for .NET 7 API with Salesforce as external Identity Provider?

Tags: .net, authentication, salesforce

I am trying to implement a REST-API in .NET 7, where the external front end client needs to authorize with an AccessToken, which was obtained in an OpenID-Connect flow.
The front end client is communicating with a Salesforce instance and gets it's AccessToken to access the REST-Backend.

The authorization in the client vs the Salesforce instance is working correctly, all information on the user is correctly being retrieved in the front end.

But when sending the AccessToken to my .NET 7 Backend, I only receive a 401-Unauthorized-Answer with www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token". There is no other hint as to why the token is invalid (i.e. wrong authority, etc.)

Edit: I changed my Log-Level-Settings in the NET7 API as Tore Nestenius suggests in his blog (down in the comments).

The Error-Messages look like this now.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No SecurityTokenValidator available for token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
```

These Error-Messages make me think, that my configuration is lacking a securityTokenValidator of some kind, which I will now investigate further.

My Configuration in program.cs looks as follows:

```
using ExampleSP_OpenIDAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200/", "https://localhost:4200/basics/home" )
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISalesforceService, SalesforceService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication(); // allegedly not needed in .NET 7 anymore

app.UseAuthorization(); // allegedly not needed in .NET 7 anymore, but when disabling CORS Problem appears

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Additionally I added an Authentication entry to my appsettings.json which I am not 100% sure gets applied which looks like this

```
  "Authentication": {
    "Schemes": {
      "Bearer": {
        "Authority": "https://xxxxx.my.salesforce.com",
        "ValidAudiences": [
          "https://localhost:4200/",
          "https://localhost:4200",
          "https://localhost:7055"
        ],
        "ValidIssuer": "xxxxx.my.salesforce.com"
      }
    }
  }
```

My Controller looks as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ExampleSP_OpenIDAuth.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public ISalesforceService SalesforceService { get; set; }

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, ISalesforceService salesforceService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            SalesforceService = salesforceService;
        }

        [EnableCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins")]
        [HttpGet("private")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Private()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Message = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #1, I would first, do all the configuring of JwtBearer in code, because doing it in appsettings, #2, I wrote a blog post about "Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core" at https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: #1 What do you mean? I think the last part of the sentence has gone missing. 
#2 Thanks for the link. I already read some of your hints, especially changing the log level accordingly got me further, because the error message is now more verbose.

I will edit my post and include it.

Comment: I mean, it is easy to make a typo in AppSettings (or use the wrong environment), and if you do, JwtBearer might get the wrong config, so I usually start with configuring it in code instead, so that I can be sure it gets the expected config values.

Comment: What response error header do you get if you set opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true; ?

Comment: The response header (401) wierdly stays the same (Www-Authenticate:
Bearer error="invalid_token" with no extra information why the token is invalid) when setting the opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true as also stated in your blog.

I included the Error Messages which appear on Backend side in my original post.

Comment: can you post a sample copy of the access token that you try to send to it?

Comment: The AccessToken received from the external Identity Provider has a similar structure (obfuscated):
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXX.xxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I am not quite sure if that helps you. 
In OIDC I use the Code Flow mechanism, but that is only important in the previous steps before authenticating against the API ,I think.

I just tried to validate the token in https://jwt.io/ but it seems like the jwt is not formatted correctly.

Comment: can you post a sample access token that does not contain any sensitive content? the access token string that you send to the API must start with ey.... All tokens start with those two characters.

Comment: In my front end application I receive a refresh token, an AccessToken and an IdToken. The IdToken is the only token which is starting with 'ey...'. 
The AccessToken starts with 00D090...

Comment: Then if the access token does not start with ey... then its not a JWT token, instead it is probably a reference token , a token that you need to pass back to the token service to exchange for the real user data (token data).  see https://dev.to/frzmohammadali/complete-guide-on-oauth-20-reference-tokens-in-aspnet-core-7-using-openiddict-2bfk

Comment: I am using https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc as front end application. After successful authentication in Salesforce a table with different tokens is displayed there. A module is also prepared, to send the AccessToken. As you mentioned before, it seems to be a reference token.

When sending the IdToken to my NET7 API instead via Postman, I get "Successfully validated the token.
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
Authorization was successful." But I think it's not correct to send the IdToken to the Backend as stated in different sources.

Comment: No, the ID-token is never meant to be sent to any API, its only intended for the client to get information about you. Also, its lifetime is rather short and you can't renew it.

Comment: [https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference) _OAuth 2 core specifications say nothing about the access token format. A common format used for access tokens is JWT, and a standard structure is available. However, this doesn’t mean that access tokens should be in that format._

Comment: That is correct, but AddJwtBearer is meant for JWT tokens. I haven't used reference tokens, so I can't tell you how to fix that.  OpenID Connect is the spec that uses a ID-token in the JWT format. Access token can be in any form. that all depends on the token provider.

Comment: I finally managed to change the format of the AccessToken issued by SalesForce in the config of our SalesForce-Instance as explained here: [Enable JSON Web Token (JWT)-Based Access Tokens (Beta)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_enable_jwt.htm&type=5) 
Now I finally get a proper error description in the response header, which leads me to further investigations (
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found")

Comment: The kid in the token must be found in the public sales force JWKS document.

Comment: So now I reconfigured in .NET the Authority, Audience, ValidIssuer and ValidAudience. All of them now point to our Salesforce instance. I am not quite sure if that is right, I assumed that, because that's what's included in the token.
Also when adding IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MY KEY")  and ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true the Validation works. Oddly the valdation also works when not defining the IssuerSigningKey. Is it correct, that the Discovery-Page includes the ISK so I do not need to define it myself?

Comment: AddJwtBearer should always point to the service that issued its token. Hard to tell about why it still works without issuing the IssuerSigningKey. Usually jwtbearer downloads the key from the issuer automatically.

Comment: Allright, it seems as my proof of concept is now working. Thanks for your help, Tore!